# this unsolvable equation can be graphed?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics, graphing-functions

I found something funny. Look at this particular equation

$$y = \sqrt{x^2 - x + 8}$$

Now suppose I want to find the domain for this graph. I know that the radical must be greater than or equal to zero (you can't take real solutions of negative radicands). Then all I do is set up an inequality to solve for the x values which are not possible by this graph

$$x^2 - x + 8 \ge 0$$

I solve by completing the square to get:

$$\left(x-\frac 1 2 \right) ^2  + \frac{31}{4} \ge 0$$

So far so good.

But wait. If you continue solving further, you end up having to square root a negative number...which in the real math world is not possible.

YET...if I put the initial graph function at the very top of this post on Desmos.com, I am able to get a nice graph.

[image]

WHAT IN THE WORLD?

Comment: This is hard to follow.  You correctly argue that $x^2-x+8$ is $>0$ for all $x$, so extracting a square root is not a problem for any $x$...but then you seem surprised that you can extract a square root.

Comment: Could you clarify *"If you continue solving further"* ?

Comment: Have you noticed you have a branch of hyperbola ?

Comment: When do you "end up having to square root a negative number"? The radical's inside is strictly positive for all $x$ as you've shown by completing the square.

Comment: Note that $f(x)=x^2-x+8$ has no negative values. Its vertex is at $x=-b/2a=1/2$, where it has the value $f(1/2)=31/4$.

Comment: Aside, you must dispose of this ignorant notion that square roots of negative numbers "are not possible in the real math world." This isn't even a matter of abstraction: the physical universe can not exist without imaginary numbers.

Comment: @Jerome - Maybe he meant "the $\mathbb R$eal math world". -- Regarding imaginary numbers in physics, see Gull, Lasenby, & Doran's [Imaginary Numbers are not Real](http://geometry.mrao.cam.ac.uk/1993/01/imaginary-numbers-are-not-real-the-geometric-algebra-of-spacetime/).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your key mis-step is assuming that finding $x$ satisfying the inequality

$$\left( x - \frac 1 2 \right)^2 + \frac{31}{4} \ge 0$$

means that you **have** to take the square root of a negative.

Think on a bit more of a basic level: no matter what you plug into $(x-1/2)^2$, what kind of numbers do you get? They're always nonnegative. This is seen in the graph of $f(x)=x^2$.

So, we know that the function you want to graph has domain $x$ which satisfy

$$\left( x - \frac 1 2 \right)^2 \ge - \frac{31}{4} $$

But we also know that, since we're squaring things, no matter what (real number) $x$ is,

$$\left( x - \frac 1 2 \right)^2 \ge 0 \ge - \frac{31}{4}$$

so, in fact, any real number $x$ satisfies our equation -- because the squaring essentially lets us "sandwich in" an inequality with $0$.

Comment: thanks. I can finally sleep

Comment: how would you continue solving this inequality with the 0 sandwiched in between though? Do you just remove the - 31/4 because it is no longer needed?

Comment: That would be one approach, yeah. You would get

$$\left(x -  \frac 1 2 \right)^2 \ge 0$$

Then, noting that $\sqrt{z^2} = |z|$, taking the square roots on each side gives

$$\left| x - \frac 1 2 \right| \ge 0$$

which breaks up into two cases:

$$x - \frac 1 2 \ge 0 \text{ or } x - \frac 1 2 \le 0$$

The first has solutions $x \ge 1/2$. The second has solutions $x \le 1/2$. Hence the solutions to the inequality are given by

$$\left[ \frac 1 2 , + \infty \right) \cup \left( - \infty , \frac 1 2 \right] = \mathbb{R},$$

the set of all real numbers.